# How to set maximum value of float in the migration laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want the maximum value entered into the field amount is 900000000

In the migration I set this :

```
$table->float('amount', 10, 2);
```

If I input data 900000000 in the mysql, there exist error :

```
Out of range value for column 'amount'
```

I give some example from my data amount :

```
900000000

800100200,2

1000300,32

10100000,44

etc
```

How an I solve this problem?

Comment: `$table->float('amount', 10, 2)`? I don't think that works..? Docs describe `$table->float('amount')` and `$table->decimal('amount', 10, 2)`... `float` is not limited to specific number of digits, although loses precision, so you're likely using `decimal`. If you said `decimal('amount', 10, 2)`, that's ten digits, two of which are decimal, leaving only eight integral digits, allowing you numbers up to `99999999.99`. Increase to `decimal('amount', 12, 2)` to accommodate the values you list.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks. I try change `$table->float('amount', 12, 2)` and it works.